# Как из самого React компонента получить key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

То-есть у нас есть React component, где-то его вызвали, а внутри самого компоенета мы получили ключ

Например

```
<Item key={3}>

const Item = ({key}) => {
 return <>{key}</>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам `key` в компонент не передается. Это "маркер" для *React*, чтобы он понимал, где произошли изменения, например, если компоненты созданы динамически с помощью `map`.

Если Вам нужно это значение в дочернем компоненте, явно его передайте в пропс:

```
<Item key={3} id={3}>
const Item = ({id}) => <>{id}</>
```